# React - useSelector not updated after dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a method which would use the value from `useSelector` and another dispatch which would update my value from the `useSelector`, however, it seems the value does not get updated after dispatch, for example

```
const userProfile = (props) => {
  const hasValidationError = useSelector(state => {
     state.hasValidationError;
  }

  const dispatch = useDispatch():

  const updateProfile = async (userId) => {
     dispatch(startValidation());    // <-- this would change the hasValidationError in state
     if (hasValidationError) {
        console.log('should not update user');
        await updateUser(userId);
        dispatch(showSuccessMsg());
     } else {
        conosole.log('can update user');
     }
  }
}
```

The `hasValidationError` would always be false, even if the value did changed from state, how could I get the updated value immediately after `dispatch(startValidation())` ?

I also tried something different, like creating a local state value to monitor my global state by using useState() and useEffect()

```
const [canUpdateUser, setCanUpdateUser] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect hasValidationError :>> ', hasValidationError);
    setCanUpdateUser(!hasValidationError);
  }, [hasValidationError]);
```

Then use `canUpdateUser` as my conditional flag in updateProfile (`if (canUpdateUser)`), however, this seems to work only the first time when validation triggers, but after that, the `canUpdateUser` value is always the old value from my updateProfile again...
How could I resolve this? Is there any way to ensure getting updated value from global state after certain dispatch fires?

Comment: hello where you able to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Could you maybe try from a slightly different approach (combining both) since it seems you want to be listening on changes of `hasValidationError`, using a `useEffect` with a dependency on that variable can maybe resolve your issue.

```js
const userProfile = (props) => {
  const { hasValidationError } = useSelector(state => state);
  const dispatch = useDispatch():

  const [userId, setUserId] = useState();

  const updateProfile = async (userId) => {
     dispatch(startValidation());
     setUserId(userId);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasValidationError) {
        console.log('should not update user');
        await updateUser(userId);
        dispatch(showSuccessMsg());
     } else {
        conosole.log('can update user');
     }
  }, [hasValidationError]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your idea! Unfortunately this might not work as when the component did mount, as the useEffect fires while the monitored `hasValidationError` was true, it would always try to execute the useEffect and updateUser....

Comment: Also, if `hasValidationError` value did not change, then `useEffect` would not be triggered, meaning if there is no validation error, user click save and didn't fire the updateUser...

Comment: did you solve this issue @KevD.